# Which is the most efficent of matching and replacing with an identifier every three new lines?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, nlp, text-processing

I am working with some .txt files that doesn't have structure (they are messy), they represent a number of pages. In order to give them some structure I would like to identify the number of pages since the file itself doesn't have them. This can be done by replacing every three newlines with some annotation like:

```
\n
    page: N
\n
```

Where `N` is the number. This is how my files look like, and I also tried with a simple [`replace`](http://pastebin.com/K0PdJ1TG). However, this function confuses and does not give me the expected format which would be something like [this](http://pastebin.com/ZCw63uyE). Any idea of how to replace the spaces with some kind of identifier, just to try to parse them and getting the position of some information (page)?.

I also tried this:

import re

```
replaced = re.sub('\b(\s+\t+)\b', '\n\n\n', text)
print (replaced)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the format is as regular as you state in your problem description:

> Replace every occurrence of three newlines `\n` with `page: N`

You wouldn't have to use the `re` module. Something as simple as the following would do the trick:

```
>>> s='aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\n\n\nbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\n\n\nccccccccccccccccccccccc'
>>> pages = s.split('\n\n\n')
>>> ''.join(page + '\n\tpage: {}\n'.format(i + 1) for i, page in enumerate(pages))
'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\n\tpage: 1\nbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\n\tpage: 2\nccccccccccccccccccccccc\n\tpage: 3\n'
```

I suspect, though, that your format is less regular than that, but you'll have to include more details before I can give a good answer for that.

If you want to split with messy whitespace (which I'll define as *at least* three newlines with any other whitespace mixed in),  you can replace `s.split('\n\n\n')` with:

```
re.split(r'(?:\n\s*?){3,}', s)
```

Comment: The thing is that I used tika to scrap some pdfs, somehow I spoted that every three `\n\n\n` it means that there is a new page. Any suggestion or any idea of how to be more clear?. THANKS for the help!

Comment: If that is the case, then this should work fine. I thought that your actual data might include more newlines than three, or bad whitespace, in which case `re` might be the best solution

Comment: Yeah... my data actually has some of them, which would be a `re` solution?. Also is there any way to put a header and a footer with the same: `\n\tpage: {}\n`format?.

Comment: Added regex. And I'm not sure what you mean by header and footer: at the top and bottom of the whole document? That's as simple as appending with '+' to the result.

Comment: I also got a false positive, since the first page (blank one) and has several `\n`spaces, is there any way of removing them?, something like: `translate(None, '\n\n\n\n')`?. What other approach is suitable for a task like this?.

Comment: It's pretty tough to give general recommendations without seeing the file, but to take care of whitespace at the beginning you could just make it `s.strip()`.

Comment: Thanks!, my files actually look like this: http://pastebin.com/fZ7eMnYb